# Create sqlite database using Flask-Migrate

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm working on a Flask app using SQLAlchemy to interface a sqlite database and Flask-Migrate to manage the migrations.

I generated a first migration script using

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
```

I pushed the repo to another server, and I'm trying to create the database using

```
flask db upgrade
```

**Is this the right procedure?**

---

I'm pretty sure the first time I did this, the sqlite database was created.

I'm trying to do it again on another server, and I get

```
SqlDatabaseDoesNotExistError: Database "sqlite:////absolute/path/to/sqlite.db" does not exist
```

I also get the same error if delete and try to recreate the database on the first server.

The directory exists and is writable, but the database file does not exist.

Shouldn't sqlalchemy create the sqlite database if it does not exist?

How am I supposed to create the database? Flask-Migrate documentation is not explicit about this, as this is a sqlite specific issue (other database engine wouldn't create the database automatically, I guess).

---

I managed to get it to work by first creating the empty DB file first using `touch`. Maybe that's what I did the other day, I can't remember.

Looks like a permissions issue except I don't get it.

The permissions are:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 root www-data 4096 Apr  5 18:50 sqlite
```

and I'm running

```
flask db upgrade
```

as root anyway so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Here's what I did:

```
touch sqlite/sqlite.db
chown www-data:www-data sqlite/sqlite.db
chmod 600 sqlite/sqlite.db
flask db upgrade
```

And then it works.

I still have the feeling I'm not doing it the right way.

Comment: Make sure the directory containing it is writable by the user as well!

Comment: have you set the FLASK_APP environment variable set on new server.

Comment: @KlausD. the directory exists and is writable. Only the database file does not exist.

Comment: @majin yes. Otherwise I'd get "Could not locate Flask application." error.

Comment: since you are using SQLAlchemy, you could call the method [`db.create_all()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) to deploy the database, it will create the file and the tables. (need to call it after the models are declared)

Comment: I don't call `create_all` in my production code because I think production code should not do that. This should be the role of Alembic/Flask-Migrate. I believe `flask db upgrade` is the right tool, except I don't get why I had this error.

Comment: @Jerome take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/145) about creating the database within flask-Migrate.  I think `SQLAlchemy.create_all()` could be called by a custom CLI command when you deploy the app the first time

Comment: @PRMoureu yes, the custom CLI command sounds reasonable. I'm still curious about whether it should and if yes why it does not work the way I describe.

Comment: @Jérôme any idea which package is putting the `SqlDatabaseDoesNotExistError` error? Not familiar with that exception, can you add the complete stack trace to your question?

Comment: @Miguel, problem solved, issue on my side. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR

Yes, the procedure is correct. In the case of a sqlite database, this should work.

---

Shame on me. The error came from a check I introduced a while ago in the application code to stop at init time if there is no database. I wonder how I missed that.

Since `flask db upgrade` initiates the application, we go through this check before we get to create the BD, which I didn't anticipate...

The check uses

```
sqlalchemy_utils.functions.database_exists(base_uri)
```

which in the case of a sqlite DB will return `True` if the file exists, even if it is empty, which explains the need to `touch` the file.

I removed the check. If the admin didn't launch `flask db upgrade` and the app is started with no DB, there will be no feedback until the first request to the DB. This is not ideal but this is a minor and unrelated issue.